# Null or empty string postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите, если строка пустая, как лучше ее хранить, как значение null или как пустую строку?

Comment: Единого рецепта нет, зависит от дальнейшего использования. Как например null будет интерпретироваться во внешнем языке который работает с БД. Будет ли необходимость в where писать `field = ''` или будет удобнее использовать is null. И конечно зависит от физического смысла происходящего, что означает пустая строка, что ее задали пустой или что ее не задавали

Comment: Коллега _Mike_ уже написал, что «верного» ответа нет.  Я могу только добавить, что использование `NULL` потребует дополнительной осторожности, особенно при сравнении.  Например, разница между операторами `=`, `IS`, и `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как выше написал mike, это риторический вопрос, на который нельзя ответить единогласно, но всё же, большинство использует null, так как это явно показывает, что ячейка пуста.

По сути `NULL` - объявленная, но  не инициализированная переменная или объект, в то время как '' - константа.

P.S. Пока писал этот ответ Ainar-G правильно подметил, что использовать `NULL` нужно осторожно, но добавлю, что многие языки программирования спокойно могут сравнивать `NULL`, а если же брать именно вселенную SQL, то стоит прислушаться к Ainar-G

1. field = `''`
2. field = `NULL`

[image: Разница между '' и null]

Comment: это определенно лучшее объяснение отличия NULL и '' которое я когда-либо видел